# Support of a direct sum of local cohomology modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring with unit, $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$ module. How can we show the following:

$$\operatorname{Supp}(\bigoplus_{j\ge 1}H_{I}^{j}(M))=\operatorname{Supp} M/(H_{I}^0(M)+IM)$$

Comment: I can prove one direction as follows: Let $p\notin \operatorname{Supp} M/(H_{I}^0(M)+IM)$. So $M_p=H_{I}^0(M)_p+I_pM_p$. Thus $M_p=H_{I_p}^{0}(M_p)$, i.e $M_p$ is $I_p$ torsion module and hence $H_{I_p}^{i}(M_p)=0$ for all $i\ge 1$. This implies one direction. Most of the implications above are reversible, accept one, which i dont know if it is reversible.

Comment: I dont know if $H_{I_p}^{i}(M_p)=0$ for all $i\ge 1$ implies $M_p$ is $I_p$ torsion.